# Multiple root tags error in Android Studio (Manifest - problem with <activity>)

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm just learning on Android and unfortunately, I got a mistake about "Multiple root tags" and I don't know what to do with it. I tried to move "manifest" to the bottom but it didn't work.

This is my code:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post the code using an image. Post the code as text, so that we can easily copy the code and test it ourselves while trying to figure out the problem. Welcome to StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the `<activity>` section inside the `<manifest>` like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.monika">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <activity> .... </activity>
    <activity> .... </activity>
    <activity> .... </activity>    

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Activities live inside manifest tag. Also, you are missing an application tag.

```
<manifest ... >
    <application ... >
        <activity android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity" ... >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For more understanding of the manifest file:

Please refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro

Also you can play around the google code samples that help you understand android coding.

https://developer.android.com/samples

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest looks right now. What error are you getting with manifest?

Please be clear in descriptions.